# XCode: Organizer does not show crash reports anymore

Tags: ios, xcode, xamarin.ios

there is just shortly some popup telling "symbolicating crash_XYZ",
but when it disappears, the list in "Device Logs"-tab of the XCode organizer
is empty again.

How to get the list of crashes back?

Reboot (iPhone), 
Re-Sync (iTunes) did not help

Answer (score 2):

if your organizer, choose “Devices” on top.
Below, in the left sidebar, you have the “Library” section and the “Devices” section.

In the Library, you should see “devices logs” where you will find all the logs (including crash logs) of all the devices you connected to your mac.

In the Devices, you can click on a device to see its specific logs.

Comment: Sorry, but - as i wrote - i know those locations and i am on the "devices logs".
But still, the list stays empty.
When an crash happens or has happened, there is just this popup shortly showing up - but then the list stays empty (0 entries for 0 applications)

Comment: sorry, I read too fast. Rebooting xcode doesn't do much more ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem, this is what I did: It's a kludge but you can copy crash logs from Settings.app under General > About > Diagnostics & Usage and paste into an email to yourself.